# WCF service and CORS

Tags: wcf, google-chrome, cors

I am facing a problem specific to chrome in posting a CORS request. The request always fails in pre-flight request of OPTIONS. In IE 11, the pre-flight request is not sent at all.

My request is sent using jQuery like this  -

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/Family/MessengerService.svc",
        crossdomain: true,
        headers: {
            "SOAPAction": '"http://home/FamilyConnect/MessengerService/IMessengerService/Conversation"',
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapRequest,
        processData: true,
        complete: function (xmlHttpResponse, status) {
            if (status == 'success') {
              //Code to parse the return value.
            }
        },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
```

My request header is this -

```
OPTIONS /Family/MessengerService.svc HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:51481
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, soapaction, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:51481/Ping.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
```

Response header I am receiving is this -

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:51481
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, soapaction, content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Date: Fri, 06 Feb 2015 21:50:24 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

The services configuration file has following configuration -

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:51481"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="accept, soapaction, content-type"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
 </system.webServer>
```

I could not figure out why is the pre-flight request failing? 
The request fails with HTTP error code 400 - Bad Request. From the request and response headers, I am guessing my request sent from jQuery is fine.
Should I look at my IIS 8.5 configuration? If so what should I do?
Search on SO and Google yields more results where the service is RESTful and data exchange pattern is JSON or JSONP. Now, should that mean Xml with SOAP protocol is not a good candidate for CORS request?

Comment: Is it mandatory to decorate the WCF Service operations with WebGet attribute to succeed in pre-flight requests? Since, my methods have only the OperationContract attribute and no WebGet attributes. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the WCF service expected to have AspNetCompatibilityMode set to True? Please help!!

Comment: Please guide me constructively, if I have structure the question better to get some answer.